# React - Parent component DidMount earlier than children

Tags: reactjs

Till now, I always thought React lifecycle worked this way:

```
<ComponentA>
  <ComponentB />
</ComponentA>
```

1. ComponentA (componentWillMount)

   1.1. ComponentB (componentWillMount)

   1.2: ComponentB (componentDidMount)
2. ComponentA (componentDidMount)

So, the parent always had to wait for the children to be rendered in order to complete the DidMount state.

However, I found that on complex Components I have, this does not happen.

It calls:

1. ComponentA (componentWillMount)
2. ComponentA (componentDidMount)
3. ComponentB (componentWillMount)
4. ComponentB (componentDidMount)

Can this really happen? (Or I might be doing something wrong)

What is it supposed to be in the DOM if ComponentA rendered without rendering it's children (ComponentB) yet?

Comment: Can you reproduce this in jsfiddle/codepen?

Comment: Don't think so, its a lot of code. It's not an easy sample code, thats why I did the question generic, to be sure if thats the expected behaviour. Sorry :(

Comment: Technically the life-cycle methods only guarantee that your particular component is mounted. It doesn't make any promises with regard to it's children. Relying on this order is usually indication that you're breaking the encapsulation boundaries of components.

For example, if your component renders another component, that component may choose to delay rendering it's children while loading data (even if they're passed from above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hard work debugging, I found out which the problem was:

I was using for one of the chilren Components this [SizeMe](https://github.com/ctrlplusb/react-sizeme) HOC.

Reading the source code of that library I checked it's render creates either the "WrappedComponent", either a "PlaceHolder".
Therefor, it was creating this PlaceHolder, making that component to be considered Mounted, when it still had not render my real children.

Here you can see [SizeMe.js code](https://github.com/ctrlplusb/react-sizeme/blob/master/src/sizeMe.js):

```
/**
 * As we need to maintain a ref on the root node that is rendered within our
 * SizeMe component we need to wrap our entire render in a sub component.
 * Without this, we lose the DOM ref after the placeholder is removed from
 * the render and the actual component is rendered.
 * It took me forever to figure this out, so tread extra careful on this one!
 */
const renderWrapper = (WrappedComponent) => {
  function SizeMeRenderer(props) {
    const {
      explicitRef,
      className,
      style,
      size,
      disablePlaceholder,
      ...restProps,
    } = props;
    const { width, height } = size;

    const toRender = (width === undefined && height === undefined && !disablePlaceholder)
      ? <Placeholder className={className} style={style} />
    : <WrappedComponent className={className} style={style} size={size} {...restProps} />;

    return (
      <ReferenceWrapper ref={explicitRef}>
        {toRender}
      </ReferenceWrapper>
    );
  }
  ...
```

So, I can assume that **yes**, the lifecycle order works as I assumed on first instance

Comment: Thanks....ran into the same issue. It looks like if you pass noPlaceholder=true in the sizeMe options, it will render the child first.

Answer (score 2):

I was curious, so I put together a [simple example in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ls9xam0j/)

```
var Container = React.createClass({
  componentWillMount: function() {
    return console.log("Container will mount");
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    return console.log("Container did mount");
  },
  render: function() {
    return <div>{this.props.children}</div>;
  }
});

var Child = React.createClass({
  componentWillMount: function() {
    return console.log("Child will mount");
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    return console.log("Child did mount");
  },
  render: function() {
    return <div> Hello World </div>;
  }
});


ReactDOM.render(
  <Container>
    <Child />
  </Container>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

This produces the output

> Container will mount
>
> Child will mount
>
> Child did mount
>
> Container did mount

which lines up with your initial expectation.

Not sure if this helps you at all.

Comment: I had already tested that long ago to make sure it worked like that. But thanks anyway :) I already found what was happening! :)